# How to pass a Java Map as a Tiles template attribute?

Tags: dictionary, configuration, struts2, apache-tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

Is there a way to pass a java Map inside a tiles template definition?

Something like this:

```xml
<definition name="my.template.name" extends="another.template">
   <put-attribute name="breadcrumbs" value="{'home':'home.action'}"/>
</definition>
```

The only workaround I found is to pass the map as a JSON String (as in the previous example), create a JSON object from it and then converting it to a Java Map.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? How do you going to use this map?

Comment: I am using this map to make a configurable breadcrumb: each entry in the map has a page label  as key and a page url as value. For instance, `{home:home.action, profile: profile.action}` renders this breadcrumb: `Home > Profile`

Comment: You can try to use couple [`list-attributes`](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/list-attributes.html) (additional bonus is that you can inherit `list-attributes`). But IMO you're better off to do it with some S2 interceptor or maybe single attribute in tiles with some logic in dedicated action/jsp.

Comment: If you pass it to tiles template, then you can get it from tiles template as string, then you can parse it, etc.